# Mongodb can't find object with too long _id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have a little bit strange situation.

I persist objects in collection "refs" explicitly setting _id.
So I have objects with very big id's.

```
db.refs.find().sort({_id: -1});
// {_id: 9200000000165761625}
// ...
```

But when I try to find object with biggest id in mongo shell it returns nothing:

```
db.refs.find({_id: 9200000000165761625}); // nothing
```

But!

```
db.refs.find({_id: 9200000000165761625}).count(); // return 1
```

How could this happen?

Comment: What about db.refs.count({_id: 9200000000165761625})

Comment: I have the same problem trying to use twitter IDs as my _id. Changed python loader code to use str(tweet.id).

Answer (score 0):

i could not reproduce your problem. i was able to successfully query on the _id value you specified. 
[image]

ensure that when you are querying you are passing correct collection name

Comment: FYI the problem is still evident in your screen shot: values longer than JavaScript's maximum safe integer cannot be safely represented in the `mongo` shell. The `_id` you inserted doesn't match the value you are searching for (mathematically) but both end up having the same representation as a JavaScript Number.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript currently only has a single numeric type `Number`, which represents all values as 64-bit floating point values. The maximum safe integer representation in JavaScript's native Number type is 2<sup>53</sup>-1 or 9007199254740991 (as returned by the constant [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)).

Any integer values beyond the safe range cannot be represented distinctly, so two or more mathematical values will map to the same JavaScript Number.

You can see this effect in the `mongo` shell with values adjacent to your provided `_id` (which is larger than the safe integer size):

```
> 9200000000165761624
9200000000165762000

> 9200000000165761625
9200000000165762000

> 9200000000165761626
9200000000165762000
```

However, these driver/client limitations are distinct from the underlying data types used in MongoDB's [BSON format](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) for documents. BSON has a 64-bit integer type which represents the full range of values: up to 2<sup>63</sup>-1 for 64-bit integers.

Your example `_id` is within the 64-bit integer range so you should be able to insert or update this using a driver with support for 64-bit integers, but would not be able to safely query or manipulate long values in the `mongo` shell or other JavaScript environments. To avoid unexpected outcomes you may want to use a different data type for these long `_id` values.