# Mongoose Node Express need _id Number with at least 18 positions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, long-integer

I am using MEAN Stack with Node, Express and MongoDB (mongoose ODM) in the backend.
Now, I have a schema model for a collection that has an _id value that is overwritten and that should be represented by a long or another big number datatype with at least 18 positions. I wanted to use mongoose-long for that.
The reason for that is, that I have some kind of "compound key" from 2 collections, which I represent by 12 positions from one collection, and then increment the other 6 number positions from the other collection which I increment by 1. This way, I can associate which of the collections belong together by the number prefix.

However, when I generate some data (float) and enter a long number for _id like "123456789123456778" and pass it to the mongodb, it gets saved, but there seems to be a rounding to the last three positions (hundreds) of the number when I query for the id field.
Also, if I increment the number by 1, it cannot save the entry because of duplicate keys. Is this a mongoose / MongoDB problem, or is it rather a javascript or python client side problem? I have read here: [Mongodb can't find object with too long _id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457516/mongodb-cant-find-object-with-too-long-id), that you can't query too long id numbers, maybe it is the same for entering too long numbers...

```
name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: dnz.fps index: _id_ dup key: { : 1.234567891234568e+17 }',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  index: 0,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: dnz.fps index: _id_ dup key: { : 1.234567891234568e+17 }',
  getOperation: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function] }
```

Is there some workaround for this? Or for getting the big number sizes right in MongoDB? 
I also thought about changing my data model, and using like 2 id's for my Collection, but which would change all my query logic again, and I don't know if this gets messy when I create new instances of my model. e.g. I would have to pass the id value from the created instance and insert it into the other collection in some way...

Has anybody a better idea how to work around this big number problem?

Comment: So might you now possibly understand why we don't use a long integer for a primary key? What happens when suggest a differernt number type to you and when are you going to hit "that limit"? This is exactly why an `ObjectId` is the default. since it's going to be a pretty long time before a collision becomes an issue.

Comment: well, but I can't very well query explicitly for an ObjectID, because ObjectID tells me nothing about the object that I have created and its relationship to the other table. Thats why my association is in the long number. Or is there a good way to use compound keys / foreign keys in collections in MongoDB? And is there really no workaround for long number id's?

Comment: has anybody an idea how to do this ? Is there another number type or a workaround for that big number size problem?

Comment: //PUSH has nobody an idea if numbers with more than 18 positions are allowed?